# GRANT SELECT ON sys.server_principals to usersys role. How?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, user-roles, sql-grant

I can't find an answer to this. Problem is that I need to use master database and then I don't know how to specify that I am granting this select to a role in another database. When using "use master" it doesn't work because the principal is in another database and you can't add e.g. Database.dbo.role prefixes to principles. How do I do that? Even granting through SSMS UI doesn't work.

I need this: GRANT SELECT ON Syf.sys.server_principals to  Syf.dbo.usersys

What am I missing? Am I thinking about this in a wrong way?

Even when I try it with the user on master database and call "execute as user = 'user'" and then select from sys.server_principals it still return only a few records. I apparently don't understand how these permissions work, it's beyond my logic. It seems there are some other objects that I need to grant permissions for.

I need to use "with execute as 'privilegedUser'", when I do that then we are in user context of that SP database and that user can't have permission to access sys.server_principals.? I need this because that SP deletes user and login if login with the same name exists. The reason I need to execute with the privileged user is because my database has multitenancy and every user is bound to one TenantId and when he or other user goes to delete the user, security policy complains that he has no right for that.

I found a way to do this, I have to grant select to sys.server_principals to guest user on master db, that gives guest some more privileges.

Comment: You could try looking at this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96629/how-to-grant-insert-in-a-table-that-is-in-another-database-on-sql-server-2008-r2  but I don't think it works for master  dba.stackexchange.com might be a better place to find an answer.

Comment: `sys.server_principals` is a view of server-level logins and groups. It exists only in `master` (referencing it in `Syf` just redirects it to `master`). Are you thinking of `sys.database_principals`? `SELECT * FROM Syf.sys.database_principals;` - do you see your user there? Is that the view you are trying to grant access to? What are you *actually* trying to do by granting access to that view? What is the end goal?

Comment: All logins/users are underprivileged but they have alter any login permission so that they can add new logins and users with same privileges. They also can delete users and logins and there is the problem: when they call stored procedure that deletes the user that same stored procedure needs to check if that was the last user linked to login and if login with that same name exists, if it exists then procedure deletes the login also, I do this because one login could have user in multiple databases and if all users are deleted I need to delete the login also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a solution where I don't need to use "with execute as owner" in this first procedure, but in the second one that this first one calls. In the first one, I can select everything I need from sys tables and pass the info to a second one that has "with execute as owner" which is in the schema forbidden to a user.

Even better solution:

```
 alter trigger [dbo].[AfterInsertUpdateTenant_Korisnici]
    on [dbo].[Korisnici]
    with execute as owner
    for insert 
    as 
    execute as user = original_login();
    declare @TenantId int = dbo.GetCurrentTenantId();
    revert;

    update dbo.Korisnici
    set TenantId = @TenantId
    from Inserted i
    where dbo.Korisnici.Id = i.Id;
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation on sys.server_principals, the needed permissions are:

> Any login can see their own login name, the system logins, and the fixed server roles. To see other logins, requires ALTER ANY LOGIN, or a permission on the login. To see user-defined server roles, requires ALTER ANY SERVER ROLE, or membership in the role.
>
> The visibility of the metadata in catalog views is limited to securables that a user either owns or on which the user has been granted some permission. For more information, see Metadata Visibility Configuration.

But all is not lost. We can use module signing to create a stored procedure that can allow you to do what you need to do.

```
use master;

create master key encryption by password = 'an unguessable password!'
alter master key add encryption by service master key
create certificate [CodeSigningCert]
    with expiry_date = '2018-12-31',
        subject = 'Code signing'
go
create login [CodeSigningLogin] from certificate [CodeSigningCert]
grant alter any login to [CodeSigningLogin]
go

SELECT 'CREATE CERTIFICATE ' + QUOTENAME([name]) 
    + ' AUTHORIZATION ' + USER_NAME([c].[principal_id]) 
    + ' FROM BINARY = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CERTENCODED([c].[certificate_id]), 1)
    + ' WITH PRIVATE KEY (BINARY = ' 
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CERTPRIVATEKEY([c].[certificate_id], 'f00bar!23'), 1)
    + ', DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''f00bar!23'')'
FROM [sys].[certificates] AS [c]
WHERE [name] = 'CodeSigningCert'

use tempdb
go
create master key encryption by password = 'foobar!23'
-- c/p the create certificate code generated above here
-- to create the same certificate in tempdb
create user CodeSigningUser from certificate CodeSigningCert
go
create login [foobar] with password = 'foobar!23'
create user [foobar]
go
create procedure dbo.listServerPrincipals
as
begin
    select *
    from sys.server_principals
end
go
grant execute on dbo.listServerPrincipals to foobar
go
execute as login = 'foobar'
go
exec dbo.listServerPrincipals
revert
go

add signature to dbo.listServerPrincipals by certificate [CodeSigningCert]
go

execute as login = 'foobar'
go
exec dbo.listServerPrincipals
revert
go
```

It seems like a lot, but in essence you're doing the following:

1. creating a certificate in master
2. creating a login from that certificate
3. creating that same certificate in your user database (I used tempdb as a standin here)
4. create a user for that certificate
5. create a login/user to represent your application user
6. create a procedure that does the select
7. try to execute it as the app login. it "works", but looks no different than if you'd done the select yourself
8. add a signature to the procedure
9. try to execute the procedure again. this time, it should return all the data

Comment: Can you explain why are you using certificate? Is it because of this line: "add signature to dbo.listServerPrincipals by certificate [CodeSigningCert]", is cert giving SP the right to select from sys.server_principals?

Comment: At a high level, yes. The creating of a user and login from that certificate is also needed (the login so that permissions can be attached to it; the user so that it can be linked to the login).

Comment: It didn't work: "The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'server_principals', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'." throw it on this line "exec dbo.listServerPrincipals". I was using my database instead of tempdb.

Comment: Hmm… sounds like something didn't go correctly. Work backwards. Check that there's a row in `sys.crypt_properties` for your procedure (that indicates that it's signed), that the user exists for the certificate, and that the login exists for the same certificate.

Comment: If this solution worked for you, consider marking it as the accepted answer. Not because I'm in this for internet points, but rather it helps those that come after you to know that you thought this solution best. But I'm not going to lie… those internet points feel good, too. :)

Comment: Well, your example works, but it does not work in my situation and certificate is not needed, it works without it. Because I need to use "with execute as 'userName'" as a "with" statement in a procedure and that automatically uses database user, not log in and DB user can't see the sys.server_principals.

Comment: Haha... So I solved the problem that you said you had and didn't read your mind to solve the problem you actually had. *shrug*

Comment: No, read the question again, especially the last part. It does not solve my problem and certificate is not needed. Use "with execute" in procedure and tell me if it works, your solution does not include "with execute",  it's not the same as "execute as login".

Comment: And also the title of this question is "GRANT SELECT ON sys.server_principals to usersys role. How?" Your solution just uses "execute as login" which needs to have permission and all else is not needed.